# Webrtrc: can a peer be relayed?

Tags: webrtc

Because of its peer2peer topology, it looks very hard to create multi users chats where number of users>10

I know there are some attempts with SFU/MCU servers but these are quite complex to be run.

My idea is simply: have a chromium browser (or chrome) on a server as relay for peers

ex: 
user1<------>chromium on server<------->user2

so this chromium is simply the server relay for all users.

Can that be done ?

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve from having one browser client be a "server"? Your diagram only shows 2 users. Maybe start with describing the problem you mean to solve? See [webrtc samples](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/multiple-relay/) for a relay example.

Comment: You may have look SFU https://mediasoup.org/

Comment: The goal is to have chrome a sfu server instead of using media soup for instance : since chrome can receive and send peer : it can act actually as a peer relay without any process. This Is of course useful if your chrome runs an a powerful server and can relay hundreds of peers

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, your requirement is to stream one or more video sources to 100's of users.

Factor to Consider before choosing the solution:
 1. Bandwidth : proportional to no.of streams(viewers)
 2. CPU : Media encoding/decoding's

Chrome can send relay the stream to multiple users, but it will consume more CPU than SFU/MCU
First Chrome need to decode the incoming media stream, 
then it has to encode output media stream separately for each endpoint, so it will consume more cpu. (`N Viewers -> N times cpu`).

If you use SFU, there will be no media decoding/encoding, so less CPU usage. With latest chrome you can scale the bandwidth with VP9 SVC at SFU.

SFU are not that complex :) There are so many [options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC_Gateway) available in different languages.
Janus (C), Jitsi(Java), Licode(NodeJS), Kurento(C++ and plugins avaliable for many languages), Medooze(java+C), many more

Choose one, personally i feel [janus](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway) is very simple.

**If you want to stream the source to thounsands then look for the cdn solutions like wowza, red5 etc**